# Apache config FreeBSD vs Debian

Tags: apache-httpd, freebsd

Long time Debian person, experimenting with FreeBSD.

TL;DR - Should I set up Apache config the way I'm used to, or like the distribution does?

I really like the way Debian's Apache config is handled/set up.  With the -available directories and -enabled directories, and using separate config files for each virtual host, linking from -available to -enabled.  Same with modules and config options like PHP or SSL.

I've just started checking out apache on FreeBSD, and I've noticed that the version I installed via `pkg install apache24` uses one massive configuration file.

Is there any reason to not back `httpd.conf` up and change at least the host definitions over to the Debian style? I typically remove the default host definitions and only use ones I want to serve up, with a catch all that serves nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from using the Debian style directories.

Create `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` directories.

Be sure to not forget that vhosts inside `sites-enabled` are symlinks to `../sites-available/vhost_name.conf`.

Then do the include to `sites-enabled` at the end of the configuration file.

As mentioned, I prefer the vhosts definition ending as .conf, so add to the end of `httpd.conf`:

```
Include sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: Thanks.  I know that technologically I can do it - as you said, just add teh Include directive.  However, I'm also wondering about Best Practices, and learning how to do things the FreeBSD Way.  If nothing better comes along though I'll mark you as the answer.